# ASP.NET Mono: How to send SOAP instead of HTML?

Tags: asp.net, html, soap, mono, webmethod

I have an ASP.NET web service based on SOAP built on top of Mono.
If I throw exceptions inside the service, the exceptions remain on the HTTP+HTML level. What I'd like to do is send always all exceptions as SOAP responses, i.e. I don't have any normal aspx pages (everything should work with SOAP).

I've tried handling all exceptions in the `Global.asax.cs` file within the `Application_Error()` method, but it seems to always send the exceptions as HTML.
What I see is the generic ASP.NET error page.

My SOAP client, when pointed to the HTML, informs me that it cannot parse HTML.

Sending SOAP from the server works nicely when no exceptions are thrown.

I've studied various web sources and learned that `Application_Error` shouldn't be used for SOAP exception handling from this resource:
[Handling and Throwing Exceptions in XML Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds492xtk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Do I have to implement my own HTTP Module or
[ExceptionUtility Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.exceptionhandling.exceptionutility.aspx) or HTTP Handler?

I am running this on my development machine:
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.5 (Debian 2.10.5-1); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1

I am testing this with MonoDevelop's built-in xsp HTTP server inside Ubuntu 11.10.

Here is my test code:

Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

namespace SoapTaikina
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected virtual void Application_Start (Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Backend.Initialize();
        }

        protected virtual void Application_Error (Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This doesn't appear to be executed when Foo() throws an exception.
            // I cannot catch the Foo() constructor exception here.
            throw new SoapException("This is never reached.", null);
        }

        // These are not used in this example.
        protected virtual void Session_Start (Object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest (Object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        protected virtual void Application_EndRequest (Object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        protected virtual void Application_AuthenticateRequest (Object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        protected virtual void Session_End (Object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        protected virtual void Application_End (Object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    }
}
```

Foo.asmx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SoapTaikina
{
    public class Foo : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            // This may throw an Exception which will not be caught in
            // Application_Error().
            //
            // This is the problem spot.
            Backend2.InitializeMoreStuff();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public bool DoStuff() {
            // This works fine and returns a SOAP response.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to do Application_Error() in global.asax? If so, I might think about moving the web services under a subdirectory with a default Global.asax that doesn't handle exceptions via HTML message

Comment: @djechelon I'm unsure whether I actually need it in Global.asax. Your suggestion sounds interesting. What would be the correct way to handle this?

Comment: I can't recreate the issue in local environment (seems that Visual Studio debugger always drops me a couple of lines of text when I throw an exception) but I think I found a feasible solution. As soon as it works I'll post it.

Comment: Can you do a test on .NET to verify that it shows the same behaviour as Mono? I found that exceptions raised by web services are never handled by Global.asax (link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error.aspx).

Comment: @djechelon I can verify that. It's annoying but you can catch those. I can't imagine that you can in mono either but it'll be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

#### First, theory

Application_Error is never fired according to .NET Framework requirements. This is because the pipeline that runs pages is different from the one that runs web services. Also, notice that throwing exceptions in Application_Error is a very bad idea.

I found that testing web services from the browser (where, and probably **because**, accept header is not set to `application/soap+xml` but to `text/html`) makes a plaintext message appear. If the client is a SOAP proxy (ie you generated in Visual Studio/MonoDevelop from the web service's WSDL) and inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol then **it is expected** that the exception is always thrown as `SOAP fault`.

#### Second, practice.

You do `var f = new Foo()` from `Application_Start`. This is wrong because the web service skeleton class is instantiated fresh new on every HTTP/SOAP request, and should never be initialized in the special `Application_Start` method that is run on the very first request and without the request itself bein processed yet. Also, you should *avoid* to do complex things (that may throw exceptions) in web service's constructor. This is just a bad design, not a non-compiling or non-working solution.

Your problem probably occurs because the ASP.NET pipeline never reached the point where the request is mapped to a web service handler rather than a page handler, firing default behaviour. Tried to find the code in mono repository, no luck :)

I suggest you to first remove any WS initialization in `Application_Start`, and if you said you don't really need it, throw away `Application_Error`

Comment: Sorry, the new Foo() call was unnecessary. I updated the code examples to point to a more realistic case. I have some backend code that might throw exceptions when initializing a persistent database connection etc. - and these are not sent as SOAP.

Comment: Again, if Backend.initialize is the cause of your problem then the exception is never thrown as SOAP. If we both assume that Backend.initialize doesn't throw, or is try-catch surrounded (bad idea), then we can start thinking about a problem. Backend2.initialize is correct there. Still, can you do initialization stuff on every web service method, at the beginning? Not the best idea, I understand, but I would try it first. I'll updte my test case